# Forcing a templated object to construct from a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a fictional class:

```
template<typename T> class demonstration
{  
    public:
    demonstration(){}
    ...
    T *m_data;
}
```

At some point in the program's execution, I want to set `m_data` to a big block of allocated memory and construct an object `T` there.

At the moment, I've been using this code:

```
void construct()
{
    *m_data = T();
}
```

Which I've now realised is probably not the best idea... wont work under certain cirumstances, if `T` has a private assignment operator for example.

Is there a normal/better way to do what I'm attempting here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use placement `new`:

```
new (m_data) T();
```

Placement `new` is really just an overload of the `operator new` function that accepts an additional parameter – the memory location where the object should be constructed at. This precisely matches your use-case.

In particular, this is how `allocator`s usually implement the [`construct`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/construct/) method which is used (among others) by the STL container classes to construct objects.

Since placement `new` only *constructs* an object without allocating memory, it’s usually an error to call `delete` to get rid of the memory. Destruction has to happen by calling the destructor directly, *without* freeing the memory:

```
m_data->~T();
```

Notice that this syntax for calling the destructor doesn’t work for a constructor call, otherwise we wouldn’t need placement new in the first place. I.e. there’s no `m_data->T()`.

Comment: So placement new is simply used to construct an object at a location, as I need. Does it go with a placement delete? Or in this case, can new stand alone?

Comment: @SalamiArmi: You don't use any "placement delete". Instead, you need to manually call the destructor when you're done: `m_data->~T()`. This is because `delete` deallocates memory. You just want to get rid of the `T` there. Later you'll have to free the memory `m_data` points to, somehow.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, rlbond. Was just curious if there was some odd behaviour involved.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @SalamiArmi: Well spotted, I forgot to mention that. I’ve updated my answer accordingly. But @rlbond has already given the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Placement `new` operator is what would suit your situation.